# IPhone Memory Management: What do I need to release inside dealloc?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So say in my viewcontroller's .h file I have:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
IBOutlet UIView *myView;
IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView;
IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;

NSNumber *myNumber; 
NSString *myString;
NSMutableArray *myArray;

UILabel *myCurrentLabel;
SomeObject *myObject;

CGPoint myPoint;    
}
```

... now in the viewcontroller's .c file

```
- (void)dealloc {

[myLabel release];
[myView release];
[myImageView release];
[myButton release];

[myNumber release]; // is this necessary?
[myString release]; // is this necessary?
[myArray release];

[myCurrentLabel release];
[myObject release];

// I don't need to release myPoint because it's a struct

[super dealloc];
}
```

Please see my comments in the .c file, I'm just wondering if my release statements are correct (and if not, why)...

Thank you!!

Comment: Two things: 1. It's impossible to say weather "this is necessary" since you did not provide the code in which your objects are initialized. 2. The correct title should be "what do I need to release", since you almost never dealloc directly.

Comment: I'm just looking for generalities. From my types you could deduce how I use them in code.

Comment: No, you couldn't. If it's [[NSString alloc] init] you do have to release, if it's [NSString stringWithFormat:...] you don't...

Comment: Memory management in objective-c is the most fundamental part of your app to get right.  I highly suggest going through a tutorial before proceeding to do ANYTHING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your init code, it is impossible to tell. As a general rule, you need to release anything that you init that is not autoreleased. For example:

```
//AUTORELEASED
NSArray *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"foo"];                       

// NOT AUTORELEASED
NSArray *array2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObject:@"foo"];                

// AUTORELEASED
NSArray *array3 = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObject:@"foo"] autorelease];
```

In the above 3, you would only have to release array2 if you do not replace them with any other code later on.

Comment: right.. okay, so i just need to release something that doesn't have alloc next to it. otherwise, it's auto-released. btw, i understand that autorelease means it'll get released at the end of a ui event. but if say an object was created in my viewDidLoad then when would it get autoreleased?

Comment: also, I never specifically did an alloc to myButton in code (as it's just an outlet).. but I guess for that i still need to manually release it?

Comment: autoreleased object may get released on exit from current scope - so in your case it may be released right after viewDidLoad method and so may be invalid after that

Comment: @Shnitzel, iboutlets are separate story - their memory management is defined by attributes of the property declared for them. If you have not declared property then they will be retained by default - so you need to release then in dealloc method.

Comment: @Vladimir, okay.. actually most of these iboutlets do have properties associated to them. but they have retain in the attributes so i should release them... got you.

Answer (score 1):

NSNumber and NSString are objective-c classes and you **can** release their instances. However whether you actually **need** to do that depends on whether you take ownership of the objects when assigning value to them (that is - whether you retain the value) or not.

So you release an object only if you retained it previously (or obtained it using methods containing alloc, new or copy - as per naming guidelines) either explicitly or via property with retain or copy attribute.

In general, I think, you must retain your ivars to be sure that their values will be valid through object's lifetime so release will almost certainly will appear in my classes' dealloc method :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using properties, use property syntax and set them to `nil` in dealloc; the setter will do the "right thing" according to whether the property is declared retain/copy and assign.

Release what you own. Be careful about dangling pointers for things you don't own.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read the Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa before doing anything else.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html